# Multiline for WPF TextBox

Tags: wpf, textbox, multiline

I am developing an app for sending some feedback.

Basically I'm trying to make a `TextBox` for comments, but I'm used to the WinForms `MultiLine=true`. I've set `MinLines` to 3, which is getting there, but preferably I'd like it if the user is able to type wherever in this block - like press enter and do dot points sort of thing. For example:

```
- Item 1        blah
- Item 2                blahlb lahbvl   d
```

But at the moment the text all stays on one line.

```
- Item 1         blah - Item 2                      blahb blahb blah
```

These comments will then help fill the body of an email which is sent. It may be pointless if I can't easily keep the same formatting when putting this string into the email body string (so that it looks like it does when sent as it does when typed).

Can I achieve what I'm after or do I have to leave it as all text on one line?

Answer (score 841, accepted):

Enable `TextWrapping="Wrap"` and `AcceptsReturn="True"` on your TextBox.

You might also wish to enable `AcceptsTab` and `SpellCheck.IsEnabled` too.

Comment: hey @itowlson if I creating multiline textbox with your method its work better but if I want to set textbox text counter `label1.Content = textBox1.Text.Length;` with this line its work but when I press enter in the textbox counter will increase 2 characters. how can I do this task please help me.

Comment: This happens because the newline is two characters (CR/LF). If you want to treat it as a single character, do something like `textBox1.Text.Replace("\r\n", " ").Length`. Be careful though: if this is meant as user feedback because your back end limits the number of characters, you may need to count the CR/LF as two characters if that's how the back end will count it!

Comment: I also ask this problem in this Link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18459908/multiline-issue-wpf-textbox

Comment: Also make sure that VerticalContentAlignment is set to Stretch

Comment: Also add surrounding ScrollVewer component in order to have scroll bar.

Answer (score 36):

Also, if, like me, you add controls directly in XAML (not using the editor), you might get frustrated that it won't stretch to the available height, even after setting those two properties.

To make the TextBox stretch, set the `Height="Auto"`.

**UPDATE:**

In retrospect, I think this must have been necessary thanks to a default style for TextBoxes specifying the height to some standard for the application somewhere in the App resources. It may be worthwhile checking this if this helped you.

Answer (score 35):

Here is a sample `XAML` that will allow `TextBox` to accept multiline text and it uses its own scrollbars:

```xml
<TextBox
Height="200"
Width="500"
TextWrapping="Wrap"
AcceptsReturn="True"
HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"/>
```

Answer (score 14):

The **only property** corresponding in WPF to the

**Winforms** property: `TextBox.Multiline = true`

is the **WPF** property:

```
TextBox.AcceptsReturn = true
```

or

```
<TextBox AcceptsReturn="True" ...... />
```

All other settings, such as `VerticalAlignement`, `WordWrap` etc., only control how the TextBox interacts in the UI but do not affect the `Multiline` behaviour.

Answer (score 12):

Contrary to [@Andre Luus, setting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8895082/1574221) `Height="Auto"` will not make the `TextBox` stretch.  The solution I found was to set `VerticalAlignment="Stretch"`

Comment: The default value for 'VerticalAlignment' *is* 'Stretch' [refer MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.verticalalignment.aspx). And yes, it really worked for me. It might depend on the control you placed the textbox in though, was it something non-standard?

Comment: Another likelihood is that you have a default style for textboxes defined somewhere in the scope of that TextBox that defined a different value for VerticalAlignment. I would check with Snoop.

Comment: If the container is fixed, the height auto will not work. Every parent container to the top must be able to expand. Wrapping in a scrollbar works too.