# How do I get a Texbox background to fit it's Margin size?

Tags: wpf, xaml

A small part of my UI is written like so:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Grid>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <StackPanel Grid.Column="0">
            <TextBlock Text="Keywords" FontWeight="Bold" />
            <TextBox Padding="2" Background="#eee" Margin="0,0,0,50"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
            <TextBlock Text="Exclusions" FontWeight="Bold" />
            <TextBox Padding="2" Background="#eee" Margin="0,0,0,50"/>
        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>
    <Next thingy>
</StackPanel>
```

It creates the margin correctly from one segment to the next in the StackPanel but does not stretch the background color with it. Take a look.

[image]

You also cannot type passed a single column of text. I would like to the TextBox to extend vertically so you can basically write a paragraph in it if you wanted to. Is there another type of box I should be using instead?

Comment: element Margin is a space outside of element. element Background won't be applied no matter what. you should change parent Background to color that area. for TextBox to support multiline text apply attributes suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2650144/multiline-for-wpf-textbox

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the bottom `Margin` of the `TextBox` to 50 you could set its `Height` to 50.

You should also set the `AcceptsReturn` property to `true` if you want to multiline input:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="0">
            <TextBlock Text="Keywords" FontWeight="Bold" />
            <TextBox Padding="2" Background="#eee" Height="50" AcceptsReturn="True"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
            <TextBlock Text="Exclusions" FontWeight="Bold" />
            <TextBox Padding="2" Background="#eee" Height="50" AcceptsReturn="True"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
    <TextBlock>next...</TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Did you try this or what happened?